# Java on Linux unable to read process inputstream

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, process, output

I'm spawning a process using ProcessBuilder in Java and trying to read its output:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("test.exe");
    Process process = builder.start();

    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    final List<String> queue = new ArrayList<String>();

    Thread ioThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("STARTED THREAD");
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("ADD: " + line);
                    queue.add(line);
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("Fatal Error: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    ioThread.start();

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("GOT: " + queue);
}
```

This works perfectly fine on my Windows machine, and also on a local Linux installation.

On my Linux VM's (DigitalOcean and Linode), it does not work, however, meaning that the process gets started, but the running thread is unable to add a single line to the queue (after waiting ten seconds in the main program, queue is empty whereas in Windows, the queue contains the read lines).

Thinks I've tried so far:

- redirecting the error stream to the output stream (even although I'm sure the test program is outputting lines on STDOUT
- using stdbuf with -oL and -eL... doesn't work
- trying to read byte by byte manually instead of using BufferedReader, same issue
- converting thread to a FutureTask
- switching between OpenJDK and Oracle VM

It definitely works in Windows and on some Linux machines.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a buffering issue after all: one `stdbuf` couldn't fix in this case.

Using a pseudo terminal with `script` did the trick, however, using:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command().add("script");
builder.command().add("-c");
builder.command().add(command);
builder.command().add("-f");
builder.command().add("-q");
```